# Como sobrepor um arquivo com informações do banco php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, pdf

Tenho um programa que cria o cadastro de uma ficha nele e preciso de uma função que pegue as informações cadastradas pelo usuário e preencham um arquivo pdf que já esta formatado e estilizado da forma que precisará ser.
Preciso de uma biblioteca ou função que me permita gravar informações por cima do arquivo de forma a criar uma ficha do cliente no papel

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o PHP e a biblioteca FPDF, você consegue abrir um arquivo modelo e preencher com informações. Aqui tem um exemplo de como fica o código:

```
<?php

/***************************
  Sample using a PHP array
****************************/

require('fpdm.php');

$fields = array(
    'name'    => 'My name',
    'address' => 'My address',
    'city'    => 'My city',
    'phone'   => 'My phone number'
);

$pdf = new FPDM('template.pdf');
$pdf->Load($fields, false); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Você pode baixar o código de exemplo neste link

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php